# Unable to configure Oracle weblogic 10gR3 server in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: eclipse, weblogic-10.x

I'm trying to setup a Oracle weblogic server in my eclipse oxygen, but it gets stuck, in the screenshot attached.

The oracle weblogic home and the JDK path are correct and no error.

I have done this many times previously, and the NEXT button should activate, but it's not happening this time.

[image: error snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

Goto Help->Eclipse MarketPlace -> Search for weblogic->install Oracle Weblogic Tools

Comment: I had similar issue, try to uninstall Oracle tools, and again create server instance, it will ask for installing tools